# Facebook App using Spring Social running on localhost

Tags: java, facebook-access-token

I am connecting my web app (on spring STS) to Facebook. OAUTH process successful and I am able to make connection . But facebook page is not redirecting back to my localhost.

I am using canvasPage as a redirect_uri in facebook OAUTH url.
canvasPage(redirect_uri) : "https://apps.facebook.com/springyellow"
canavsURl : "https://localhost:8444/spring-social-normal-mvc/facebook/"

After OAUTH completes : my facebook page shows the link, which is redirect link
"...//apps.facebook.com/springyellow/?code=AQBb2mQY9rHvbz...... "
and remains on facebook page does not redirect to my localhost.

If I specify redirect_link in advance settings then its shows the error..
and If I use canavsURl as a redirect_uri in Facebook authorize url.
then it falls into infinite call to my localhost..

Can anyone explain me how to redirect facebook to my localhost.

Thanks.